# Input file starting with a multicolumn

Tags: tables, input

I have constructed a table (table with a `tabularx` environment) which takes an input file as input.

When I begin this input file with a `\multicolumn` command the compilation fails and gives me the error

```
"./floats/tab_represent_SWE.tex:2: Misplaced \omit. [\multicolumn{3}{l}{\emph{By XXX}}]"
```

However, once I insert a `\\` in front of the \multicolumn everything works fine.

Any thoughts on what is wrong?

**Edit** (by touhami, `tabularx` tag removed and mwe with `tabular` is add)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline 
\input{foo.tex}
\hline 
1 & a \\ 
\hline 
2 & b \\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

**foo.tex**

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{By XXX}}\\
```

Comment: You can get some thoughts by searching this site: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&q=misplaced+omit+multicolumn+site%3Atex.stackexchange.com . If no luck, an MWE would certainly help finding the right answer.

Comment: Welcome! We have no idea how you've constructed it or what class and relevant packages you're using or what else is in the file or .... If you can't figure out the problem with the problematic code, we are not likely to have better luck without it ;).

Answer (score 2):

The TeX primitive `\input` is redefined in LaTeX to check, whether the file exists to generate a more user friendly error message. However, this cannot be done in an expandable way, which `\multicolumn` requires.

### Workaround via `\@@input`

A workaround is to use the original `\input`, stored as `\@@input` in LaTeX. Because of the category code of `@`, the table needs to be wrapped in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` or `\csname` can be used to generate the command sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\csname @@input\endcsname foo.tex
\hline
1 & a \\
\hline
2 & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, if `foo.tex` does not exist, the error behavior is less nice than LaTeX's version.

### Workaround via package `catchfile`

An alternative workaround is offered by package `catchfile`. Here, the file contents can be read in a macro, which is then used in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef\MyFooRows{foo.tex}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\MyFooRows
\hline
1 & a \\
\hline
2 & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```